# Applying a function on a pandas dataframe column using map

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am doing sentiment analysis for the first time. I am analyzing yelp reviews. I have converted the reviews into a list before writing them into a csv file. I am having some coding issues with these reviews so I am running this code.

```
df['newtext'] = map(lambda x: x.decode('latin-1').encode('ascii','ignore'),df['comment'])
```

This creates a new column(newtext) but instead of getting clean text I am getting this message

map object at 0x000001C1B9CE07F0

I am using python 3. Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Python's `map` function returns map objects, which need to be cast to lists. [Example](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html)

So, you can just cast your `map()` call in a `list()`

```
df['newtext'] = list(map(lambda x: x.decode('latin-1').encode('ascii','ignore'),df['comment']))
```

Answer (score 2):

`map` will slow things down, especially for large dataframes. You should know string columns offer vectorized methods which are much faster than maps and loops.

The pandaic way would be to call the `str` accessor methods - `encode` and `decode`, which do the exact same thing, but much faster.

```
df['newtext'] = df.comments.str.decode('latin-1').str.encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: @Analyticsbeginner Uh... `df.comments.astype(str).str.decode('latin-1').str.encode('ascii','ignore')`

Comment: error : Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: @Analyticsbeginner Sorry, can't help you without seeing what your data looks like. But whatever it is, _don't_ use the other methods. They are _slow_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It converts the map object to a list.

```
df['newtext'] = list(map(lambda x: x.decode('latin-1').encode('ascii','ignore'),df['comment']))
```

Answer (score 0):

just convert the map object into a list as shown below

```
df['newtext'] = list(map(lambda x: x.decode('latin-1').encode('ascii','ignore'),df['comment']))
```

Comment: I get this error  error 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'